# Update an attribute on a specific item in DynamoDB (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to fetch a specific item from my DynamoDB table, defined by its unique partition key, a string that I've passed into the method. I want to then change one of the string attributes from "false" to "true".

This is the code I have so far

```swift
var updatedValue: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
updatedValue.S = "true"

var updateInput: AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput = AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput()
updateInput.tableName = "knot-listings"
updateInput.key = ["ID": self.ID]
var valueUpdate: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValueUpdate = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValueUpdate()
valueUpdate.value = updatedValue
valueUpdate.action = AWSDynamoDBAttributeAction.Put
updateInput.attributeUpdates = ["Updated": valueUpdate]
updateInput.returnValues = AWSDynamoDBReturnValue.UpdatedNew

self.dynamoDB.updateItem(updateInput).waitUntilFinished()
```

`self.ID` refers to the unique identifier string. I want to select an attribute called "sold" and change its value to "true".

Answer (score 0):

I actually used your code as a guide.

Don't use

```
self.dynamoDB.updateItem(updateInput).waitUntilFinished()
```

But Instead

```
dynamoDB.updateItem(updateInput).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if (task.error == nil) {


    }

    return nil

})
```

Altogether

```
    var updatedValue: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    updatedValue.S = "true"

    var updateInput: AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput = AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput()
    updateInput.tableName = "knot-listings"
    updateInput.key = ["ID": self.ID]
    var valueUpdate: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValueUpdate = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValueUpdate()
    valueUpdate.value = updatedValue
    valueUpdate.action = AWSDynamoDBAttributeAction.Put
    updateInput.attributeUpdates = ["attributeName": newAttributeValue]
    updateInput.returnValues = AWSDynamoDBReturnValue.UpdatedNew


    dynamoDB.updateItem(updateInput).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if (task.error == nil) { 
    }

    return nil

})
```